# Can Regex support not finding something?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have a string I want to search for two sets of characters. The first one is "in" and the second one is "-in". The phrase to search is "in-in". I want to replace "in" with *8888* and "-in" with *9999*, but I can't figure out how to not match the final "in" portion.

This string is actually two substrings, one "in" and the other "-in". I've tried using string.Split, but that isn't helping.

Any thoughts/direction on .NET regex on if this is possible to end up with the string *88889999* based of replacing both in and -in? Right now, all I seem to be getting is *8888-8888*

Comment: Can you replace "-in" with 9999 as one operation, then as a second operation replace "in" with 8888?

Comment: Try look ahead and look behind. I usually do Regex with Autohotkey, the document here should help you to do it in .net. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

Comment: @576i, that may be just what I'm looking for. I'll check this out in more detail.

Comment: @Brandon, backward search is out. see my comment below.

Comment: "(?<!-)in" without the quotes should be the match for "in", but not "-in".  "(?<-)in" should match "-in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!-)\bin\b
```

matches `in` only if it's not preceded by `-`.

```
-in\b
```

matches `-in`.

The [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) make sure that you don't accidentally match `bins`, `into` or `gain`.

---

Solution:

```
Sub TestRegExSubstition()
    Dim searchDictionary As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
    searchDictionary.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("in", "8888"))
    searchDictionary.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("-in", "9999"))

    Dim sentenceArray = {"in-in",
                         "in Parvin-e",
                         "Parvin-in",
                         "in in-e",
                         "Parvin injā-in"}

    For i = 0 To UBound(sentenceArray)
        Dim input As String = sentenceArray(i)
        For Each kvp In searchDictionary
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<!-)\b" + kvp.Key + "\b")
            input = regex.Replace(input, kvp.Value)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(input)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, this is brilliant, exactly what I needed, especially guarding against accidental match. I've edited yours to put the VB.NET solution here for others in case it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your set of substitutions is not prefix-free, then you probably want to consider performing the longer substitutions before the shorter ones. In this case, you would first want to replace `"-in"` with `"9999"` and *then* replace `"in"` with `"8888"`.

Comment: sorry, I won't be able to do a backwards search on these as the order of search/replace is fixed.

Comment: Backwards search? It's just a simple substitution using `string.Replace`!

Comment: the first term to be search is "in". the second one is "-in"!

Comment: You can't change the order of substitution?

Comment: no, I can't. but as @576i pointed out, I may be able to do a look-ahead. i'm researching that now.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is strictly always in-in, why are you not using MatchCollection of the Regex ? "(in)(-in)", will let you get Match[1] = in and Match[2] = -in and you can replace them accordingly

Comment: it's not always strictly "in-in". it could be "inja-in" or "in-e" or anything else. this is not a solution though, it should be a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do following:
1. First search for "in" in the string "str" if found, replace with "8888".
2. Secondly search for "-in" in the string "str" if found, replace with 9999".

There are two solutions to your problem:
Case1 : You know at first that you are going to search for "searchString1" and "searchString2".
Solution: In this case, order your strings in the order of length from largest string to lowest string, then sequentially replace.

Case2 : You don't know at first what is the second string to search for (from your comments it looks like this is the case).
Solution: First form a KEYWORD which is not present in "inputString", replace "searchString1" with KEYWORD, then do a search for "searchString2 or -KEYWORD", replace with your second replace string, then finally replace KEYWORD with your first replace string.